# Bash: how to print the files that feature a specific given word in any line at a given location?

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to write a script that takes 2 arguments: word for any word that is to be seacrched in the files of a directory and n for the position at which that word has to be in any line in that file, and finally print only the files that feature that word at that position in any line?

My code until now is:

```sh
word=$1
for files in .
do
    grep -rl "$word" 
done
```

This only prints the files with that word in them, however, and I'm not sure how to implement the rest.

Comment: What are the possible separators between words?

Comment: just spaces i believe

Comment: "I believe": you'll have to be sure

Comment: yes there are just spaces but im only allowed to post a comment if it's more than 15 characters

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Also, _n for the position at which that word has to be_ Is _n_ row or  position on some particular ro or starting character in the file or what? Thanks.

Comment: Your example program does not have two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop seems a bit strange, you'd want to loop through all files, not through the set of things you provided (which is a set with a single entry, `.`). Not really useful at all.

So,
`for file in *` would make much more sense. Then, use that `${file}` variable! You're not even doing anything with it in your for loop! That also makes no sense.

For example, you could

1. use `read` to get lines from the file (thousands of examples on how to read lines from files using bash)
2. use `cut` to select the position
3. use `[[` / `]]` to test for the string in that position, and if successful
4. print the name of the file and skip ahead to the next file.

---

alternatively, learn your self a bit of regexes. Don't know which version of `grep` you have, but "from the beginning of the line, find the things that has N repititions the scheme "any repitititon of anything but a delimiter + one word delimiter followed by the word I'm looking for"  isn't hard.

Something like, to look for "mustard" in the fifth word:

```
words_before=4
word="mustard"
# idea is to get the sed expression '/^\([^ ]\+ \)\{words_before\}word/!{qerror_code}'
sedtemplate_start='/^\([^ ]\+ \)'
sedtemplate_end='/!{q100}'
sedtemplate="${sedtemplate_start}\\{${words_before}\\}${word}${sedtemplate_end}"
#.... open all files, go through all lines
  ( echo "${this_line}" | sed -n "${sedtemplate}" ) && echo "${file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly then the right approach is this (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v word="$1" -v pos="$2" -v ORS='\0' '$pos == word { print FILENAME; nextfile }' * |
xargs -0 cat
```

That assumes your awk supports `nextfile` and printing of `\0` (e.g. GNU awk).